# Feeding two accounts into one PST file in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst, microsoft-outlook-2019

My old dev PC crashed and I had to get a new box. One problem when reinstalling everything again: I have Office 365 and thus Outlook 2019 locally on my PC. In my previous setup, I had my two e-mail accounts both being checked with POP and storing their e-mails into one, central `.PST` file. And I liked that setup.

Now after reinstalling, I was able to quickly get my two e-mail accounts set up again - but now, Outlook insists on having two separate "worlds" - each account is a separate "subfolder" (labelled with the e-mail address) in Outlook, it now uses IMAP (which is fine by me), and also both accounts store their e-mails locally into separate `*.ost` files in a folder I had no option of choosing.

Is there any way I could:

- at least change the **location** of those `*.ost` files? I don't like where Outlook defaults to ... but I can't find the "Change Location" button that used to be present on the account setting dialog anymore...
- ideally setup the two e-mail accounts to feed into **one single, common** set of folders, and into **one common `.pst` file** again?

Setting up Outlook has become easier - no question - but it also lacks the flexibility and configurability I used to like as a power user .... any way to get that power back??

Comment: Go to Control Panel, Mail, and open that. You see Email Accounts, Data Files and Profiles. You can manage in detail in these options.

Comment: @John: thanks - those **are** the dialogs that I'm using - I **used to be able** to change location of a data file, and make two accounts send their mail into the same data file - but alas, those options do not seem to be available anymore :-(

Comment: Try change the Data file used in Profiles (click on the profile button). I have 3 accounts all landing in the same PST file.  You can back up the PST file, try creating a new Account using the Control Panel dialogue and see if you can point the new account to the data file of your choice. If that succeeds, you can import the mail from the PST file you backed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

> at least change the location of those *.ost files?

According to your description, I notice that you have configured an IMAP account. It is recommended that you could try to modify the registry to modify the location of `.ost` files.

For specific steps, please refer to:

1. Select Start, select Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then select OK;
2. Locate and then select the registry subkey:

   ```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook;

    (Note: The xx.0 placeholder represents your version of Office (16.0 = Office 2016, Office 365 and Office 2019, 15.0 = Office 2013));
   ```
3. Right-click Outlook, select New, and then select "Expandable String Value"
4. Type `ForcePSTPath`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Right-click `ForcePSTPath` and then select "Modify"
6. In the "Value" data box, type the full path of where you want to store the `.ost` file (such as `D:\MyOST`), and then select "OK"
7. On the File menu, select Exit to exit the Registry Editor
8. Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles… > Add… > type a name for the new profile > Choose Manual setup or additional server types and configure your IMAP account
9. Back to Mail window, choose Prompt for a profile to be used;
10. Open Outlook and choose the new profile.

(It should be noted that if you modify the registry by mistake, serious problems may occur. Please [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) before operation.)

Comment: Yes, thanks - I found that hint somewhere, too, and was able to at least put the `.ost` files where I want them to be. Funny thing is: to define the directory for the **`.ost`** files - one needs to set a value for **`ForcePSTPath`** (not `ForceOSTPath`, as one may think at first.....)

Answer (score 1):

Combining Accounts into one PST file still works (for PST, not Exchange).

Once the data files have been established, you cannot change where the email goes except to make a new PST file that points email where you want and then import email to the new file.

I have the newest Outlook here and the option to point email to a specific data file still exists. I use this to create a file with 3 accounts going to it.

Here is a screen shot that shows the major points. This is taken from Control Panel, Mail.

Most importantly:  I use the Manual Account setup, never the Wizard.  All the functionality we have been used to remains.

[image: Manual Outlook Data file setup]

Comment: Yes - this works as long as you're using POP as the mail protocol. That's what I had so far. It seems IMAP is **quite a different beast** - and the `.ost` files created by Outlook when using IMAP also behave quite differently. There's really no way to combine two IMAP accounts so that they deliver their mails to the same PST - each will have its own OST file - no way around that, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe you can still do this with IMAP if you are pointing it to a PST file. I saw that option when setting up the account to test. IMAP with no PST file is like Exchange .

Comment: from what I've been seeing so far, I don't think that's possible - but I'll give it another try tonight and I'll report back - thanks!

Comment: Agree. This is valid when configuring POP accounts.

Comment: Well - I tried configuring my accounts with IMAP and storing their e-mails into a `.pst` file of my choosing - but that just plain doesn't work, no matter what I tried. It seems the way Outlook handles POP vs. IMAP is quite fundamentally different. POP mails go into `.pst` files, IMAP uses `.ost`, and I found no way to "merge" the two. So I now have two additional `.ost` files, and I'll see if I can somehow at least archive my mails after 60 days into a common  `.pst` file for reference. Thanks anyways!

Comment: POP mail is downloaded to your PC and removed from the server. IMAP mail is stored on the server and kept there. So Outlook treats them differently because they are very different. For mail-on-server outlook now uses the .ost file format; which stands for "Offline Outlook Data File". It serves as a cache so you can still read your mail while offline. It does not serve as a complete store of your mailbox, it can be filtered!

Comment: You can download IMAP to a PST File if you want. I have done that for clients. But IMAP accounts works like Exchange accounts and you can just have one Exchange account in a Profile.