# Move outlook data file from to other location in terminal server

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Hi I have  a terminal server with 10 users , I have a microsoft outlook installed , i have to change the Microsoft outlook data file location from c: to N:  for all users

Comment: Why is not working?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, we can try to modify the location by registry, please refer to my answer in this thread: [Feeding two accounts into one PST file in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/1667618/feeding-two-accounts-into-one-pst-file-in-outlook#:%7E:text=It%20is%20recommended%20that%20you%20could%20try%20to%20modify%20the%20registry%20to%20modify%20the%20location%20of%20.ost%20files.).

And i notice that you want to move datafiles to other location in terminal server. Maybe you need to pay attention to this: [Limits to using personal folders files over LAN and WAN links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/data-files/limits-using-pst-files-over-lan-wan).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.